# How to tag an object that doesn't have a recognizable difference in python (and selenium)?

Tags: python, selenium

I am writing a program in python using selenium webdriver, which automates the firefox browser. One of the websites I go to has several objects that have a timer that countdown until they disappear. Some of these objects are the same. I want to be able to interact with them individually but then when they disappear, I want my program to "forget" about them and only worry about the current ones.

See picture:

http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/5349/bidsl.png

Answer (score 0):

You can check for element's presence before performing any operation on that.If the element is present then only do something with that otherwise forget it.

Comment: What if I refresh the page and the element's ID changes in selenium??

Comment: Then either you have to find a unique attribute for every locator if available or you have to find a pattern for that loactor,You better provide some code snippet for your html to get specific answer to your case.